# SharePoint 2013 search

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results

Is it possible to display the response time of search in SharePoint 2013, something like google search.

These many results in these many seconds. Search statistics webpart, is there in SharePoint 2013 or not? and wanna know whether top federated results webpart is there in 2013?

Share ideas ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no search statistics web part. And you don't get a search result took X seconds. But you do have number of search results in the bottom of the search result page - at least at Enterprise Search Center site template.